# War deployment fails only on remote server, weld.weldclassIntrospector is missing .beanmanager

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly-8

I've deployed a war successfully on a local server running on localhost. However when I deploy the WAR to my remote AWS instance, the server starts up correctly, however undeploys my WAR several seconds after startup.

Following startup, I recover the `HelloWorld.war.failed` file from the standalone/deployments directory, shown below:

```
>{
    "JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"HelloWorld.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"HelloWorld.war\".beanmanager]"],
    "JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"HelloWorld.war\".INSTALL"],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => [
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"HelloWorld.war\".beanmanager",
            "jboss.deployment.unit.\"Travlog.war\".beanmanager",
            "jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"
        ]
    }
>}
```

In particular,

```
"jboss.deployment.unit.\"HelloWorld.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"HelloWorld.war\".beanmanager]"],
```

makes me think that the root cause is a `missing/misplaced bean.xml` file, however I've done some research on this and found that in Wildfly 8.0.x there was a bug that this file was still required even though the specification no longer requires it, but I believe that this was addressed in wildfly 8.0.x

To test this theory, I added a 0-bytes `beans.xml` file to `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` directory in my eclipse project, and verified in the war that it is deployed to the `WEB-INF` directory.

Question: given that the beans.xml file is present in the correct directory, (and it is supposedly not required in Wildfly 8.2.1), what is the cause of this missing *.beanmanager dependency?

EDIT: This may be a simple rookie mistake. Instead of using the management console to upload the WAR and deploy it, I was using WINSCP to directly upload the WAR into the standalone/deployments folder. When I used the management web GUI, the war deployed successfully. Still unsure as to the mechanism for failure, however.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: edited to add question.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a simple rookie mistake. Instead of using the management console to upload the WAR and deploy it, I was using WINSCP to directly upload the WAR into the standalone/deployments folder. When I used the management web GUI, the war deployed successfully. Still unsure as to the mechanism for failure, however.